# $T\in \mathcal{L}(V)$ stabilizes a maximal flag in $V \Leftrightarrow V = \bigoplus_{i=1}^k V(\lambda_i)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, jordan-normal-form

> Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}$ and $T : V → V$ be linear. We say that $T$ stabilizes a maximal flag $\{V_i\}_{i=0}^n$ in $V$ if $T (V_i ) ⊆ V_i$ , for all $i = 1, . . . , n$. Show that, $T$ stabilizes a maximal flag in $V$ if and only if $V$ can be expressed as the direct sum of its generalised eigenspaces.

I have proved the "if" direction, and I have some trouble proving the "iff" direction.

**My work:** Let $\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$ be a basis of $V_n=V$ such that $\{v_1,v_2,...,v_i\}$ is a basis of $V_i$, where $\{0\} = V_0 < V_1 < V_2...<V_n=V$ is a flag of subspaces on $V$. The matrix of $T$ with respect to this basis is upper triangular, so that $\det(xI-T) = \Pi_{i=1}^n (x-a_{ii})$. Since the characteristic polynomial of $T$ splits over $\mathbb{F}$, so does the minimal polynomial of $T$ (the minimal polynomial divides the characteristic polynomial). As a result, we have $V = \bigoplus_{i=1}^k V(\lambda_i)$.

Now for the other direction, I begin with $V = \bigoplus_{i=1}^k V(\lambda_i)$ as the direct sum decomposition of $V$ over the generalized eigenspaces. So, the minimal polynomial of $T$ splits over $\mathbb{F}$. What do I do next? I know that the matrix of $T$ can be brought to its Jordan form. I am wondering if a basis consisting of the columns of the Jordan form of $T$ would suffice? I am not sure!

I need to create a chain of subspaces $\{0\} = V_0 < V_1 < V_2...<V_n=V$ which are $T$-invariant, to solve the problem. How do I arrive at one?

**Edit and Update**:
Since $V$ can be written as the sum of generalized eigenspaces of $T$, the minimal polynomial of $T$ splits over $\mathbb{F}$. So there is a Jordan basis for $T$, w.r.t which the matrix of $T$ is in the Jordan form (obviously). Now, we construct $V_i$ in the following manner, where $J[1],J[2],..,J[n]$ denote the columns of $J$.

$$V_i = \text{span}(J[1],J[2],...,J[i])$$

Does this work? I think that the $V_i$'s are properly contained in $V_{i+1}$, since the columns of $J$ are linearly independent (right?). As a result, we obtain a chain of size $n$. Also it seems like all these $V_i$ are $T$-invariant because the Jordan form $J$ is upper triangular.

Comment: The existence of a stable maximal flag is equivalent to the existence of a basis in which the matrix of $T$ is upper triangular. In one direction, clearly the characteristic polynomial of an upper triangular matrix splits (it is already a product of linear factors). In the other direction, if $V$ is a sum of generalised eigenspaces then we know that it admits a matrix which is block-diagonal with each block representing the action on a generalised eigenspace: one then has to show (via constructing Jordan chains, say) that each block can be made to be upper triangular.

Comment: Hmm, alright. The fact that $V = \bigoplus_{i=1}^k V(\lambda_i)$ implies that there exists a basis of $V$, say $B$ such that $[T]_B$ is block-diagonal seems to follow by constructing $B = B_1\cup B_2\cup ...\cup B_k$ where each $B_i$ is a basis of $V(\lambda_i)$ right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. In fact you can do something weaker than Jordan form and simply show that it admits a basis in which the matrix is upper-triangular (but constructing Jordan chains is not hard).

Comment: I think what I'm required to show is that for every $i$, there exists a basis $B_i$ of $V(\lambda_i)$ such that the matrix of $T$ restricted to $V(\lambda_i)$ is a Jordan Block? In other words, $T\vert_{V(\lambda_i)}$'s matrix w.r.t $B_i$ is a Jordan Block (**is this always possible?**). Then we can construct $B$ as above. **How do I go ahead from here?**

Comment: "a basis consisting of the columns of the Jordan form of $T$ would suffice?" Yes. "all these $_$ are $T$-invariant because the Jordan form $J$  is upper triangular ?" Yes of course. You're more afraid than you need to be. Nothing to be added really, except (if you're not fully convinced) a really low-level unrolling of definitions to show that the matrix is upper triangular iff the maximal flag defined by the ordered basis is stabilized by $T$.